# How to get a variable value and Pass inside a RelayMutation?

Tags: relayjs, relay, graphql-js

I'm trying to finish up a RelayMutation. And I am having a issue.

I'm trying to pass a variable value into my RelayMutation But I am not able to do it.

My Goal: When I press Accept, take the inviteAnswer variable and pass it to my RelayMutation as an input.

Right Now, I am just getting inviteAnswer as "undefined".

```js
RelayMutation.js(EventEditMutation.js)


import Relay from 'react-relay';


export default class EventEditMutation extends Relay.Mutation {
 static fragments = {
    event: () => Relay.QL`
        fragment on Event {
            id
            guests {
                user
                status
            }
        },

    `,
};

getVariables(inviteAnswer) {
    console.log(inviteAnswer);
    return {
        id: this.props.event.id,
        inviteAnswer: true,
    }
}

getMutation() {
    return Relay.QL`mutation {
        EventEdit,
    }`;
}

getFatQuery() {
    return Relay.QL`
        fragment on EventEditPayload {
            Event {
                guests
            }
        }
    `;
}

getConfigs() {
    return [{
        type: 'FIELDS_CHANGE',
        fieldIDs: {
            Event: {
                guests: this.props.event.guests,
            }
        }
    }];
}

}
```

AcceptFunction on Component

```js
accept = () => {

const inviteAnswer = true; <<<--- I want this value here!
console.log(inviteAnswer);
const { event } = this.props.viewer;
console.log(event);


const mutation = new EventEditMutation({
  event: event,
  inviteAnswer: inviteAnswer,

});

console.log(inviteAnswer)




const callbacks = {
  onSuccess: (payload) => {
    console.log('success: ', payload);
  },
  onFailure: (err) => {
    console.log('failure: ', err);
  },
};

RelayStore.commitUpdate(mutation, callbacks);
Actions.chat({eventId: event.id});
};
```

InputFields of my GraphqlMutation(EventEditMutation)

```js
export default mutationWithClientMutationId ({
name: 'EventEdit',
inputFields:{
        id: {
            type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID)
        },
        inviteAnswer: {
            type: GraphQLBoolean,
        }
    },
```

I appreciate if you guys could help me out. Thanks! Also, if you think that there is a better way to do it, please let me know.

Comment: Is the problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the mutation incorrectly.

Your mutation variable should match the input fields on the getVariables() and likewise the input fields on the receiving mutation.

```
const mutation = new EventEditMutation({
  id: event,
  inviteAnswer: inviteAnswer,
});
```

And the getVariables does not need to take an argument:

```
getVariables() {
    return {
        id: this.props.event.id,
        inviteAnswer: this.props.inviteAnswer,
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok Alexi2. I appreciate your thoughts. The problem is that the InviteAnswer can be true or false.

Comment: When you accept an Event, it's true. When you deny, it's false.

Comment: That way that you suggest will work only if InviteAnswer is true. Do you understand the point?

Comment: That is from your OP. If you want to grab the variable use this.props.inviteAnswer